# perl grep matching key from hash table

Tags: perl, hash

I'm dealing with a hash in Perl.

I use the following statement to check if a variable matches a key in my hash table. The statement already evaluates to true. So the grep works. But how can I now retrieve the hash key & value where there is a match?

```
if ( grep {/.*$var1*/} keys %my_hash ) {
  #print the key and value that results from the grep?
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can extract all the matching keys right in the condition:

```
if (my @matches = grep /.*$var1*/, keys %my_hash) {
    my @values = @my_hash{@matches};
}
```

Also, `/.*$var1*/` is weird. Do you want to apply the final asterisk to whatever comes last in the variable? Also, using `.*` at the beginning does nothing if there's no `/g`: `/$var1*/` would work the same (and maybe faster).

Answer (score 0):

```
if (@captarr= grep {/.*$var1*/} keys %my_hash ) {
}
```

`@captarr = grep (/.*$var1*/, keys %my_hash)` is a 2 argument function;
1st is regex, 2nd is array upon which the regex applied,
returning array of matched as if the 2nd arg. array is one string made of the array, searched for in global, and it'll
return nul if none is matched.
it's similar to `@captarr = $my_str ~= /.*$var1*/` with swapped argument position of LHS ~= RHS

Comment: I'd refine that a bit to the first argument being a block of code that's evaluated, with `$_` set to the value of the current entry in the list that's the second argument. If the block evaluates to a true value, then the current value of `$_` is added to the list of items "matched"; if it's false, we continue to the next item in the second argument. `map` is similar, but it returns _every_ value of `$_` after the block executes.